# How to know which all checkboxes checked using angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently using angular2. I have my HTML Code like

```
<div *ngFor="let val of channelForTabs; let i=index">
            <label for="isCheckBox" style="margin-left:15px;">Draw</label>
            <input id="checkBox{{i}}" type="checkbox" class="fitCheckbox" style="margin-left: 10px;width: 16px;" />
            <de-series-prop></de-series-prop>
        </div>
```

As many times the values in channelForTabs, those many times checkbox and the series component gets added. How to check which all checkboxes are checked without calling (change) method.

I want to know on a button click how to see which checkboxes are checked and use those corresponding series data.

Comment: There are dozens similar questions. Please try to find existing before posting a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use ngModel and ngModelChange event as below,

```
<input type="checkbox" (ngModelChange)="clickedItem(color, $event)" checked="false" [ngModel]="!color"> {{color}}<br>
```

and your method will be as

```
 clickedItem(val,event){
    if(event){
    this.selectedItems.push(val);
    }
    console.log(val);
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tamdl6paIxmYxXpm3M7r?p=preview)**

Comment: I've got you @Aravind

Comment: @krummens You need any more help?

Comment: Nope. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: It doesn't remove the elements on uncheck.

Comment: I might have not added the else statement @adrita sharma

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but if the user unchecks an option, the value will be retained in the array. It has to be spliced everytime it is unchecked.

`let indexx = this. selectedItems.indexOf(element.value);
            this. selectedItems.splice(indexx, 1);`